# Why is `NMinimize` trying to evaluate my function analytically instead of numerically?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have been having some trouble with `NMinimize`. I am trying

```
NMinimize[f[x], x]
```

where `f` is a complicated function. The whole reason I am using `NMinimize` is because `f` is too complicated to be able to compute for an arbitrary `x`, but for a fixed value of `x` it is fine.

Well `NMinimize` seemed to be taking up an outrageous amount of time and memory, so I added a print statement inside `f`

```
f[x_]:= Module[{},
Print[x];
...
]
```

and ran the `NMinimize` code again. To my surprise, Mathematica prints `x$4770`, the name of a local variable. Why is `NMinimize` calling my function with non-numeric values? How can I stop it from doing so?

Comment: Just a wild guess, try adding ?_NumericQ to the argument of the function called. see http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that putting

```
NMinimize[Hold[f[x]], x]
```

solved the issue.

Comment: While this works, it most probably is by accident and not documented, so it could change in future versions (although that is very unlikely). It has worked like that for many versions now. For a more detailed discussion see eg. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43318/169). The "supported"/documented solution for this problem is to re-define `f` to `ClearAll[f]; f[x_?NumericQ]:=...` as Nasser mentioned in his comment.