# Why does Plot[Hold[x], {x,0,1}] work?

Tags: functions, evaluation, hold

It appears that, counter to my expectation, all of these (and probably many others) seem to work fine:

```
Plot[Hold[x], {x, 0, 10}]

FindRoot[Hold[x^2 == 2], {x, 1}]

NMinimize[Hold[x^2], x]
```

I would expect `Plot` or `NMinimize` to complain that e.g. `Hold[0]` is not a number.

These were mentioned a few times on this site but didn't get any attention: [(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43310/12) [(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37184/12).

Doing this does appear to solve problems which [would normally require `_?NumericQ`](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820).

Is this usage of `Hold` supported?  Is it *meant* to work this way, does it work by design,  or is it accidental?

My guess is that these work accidentally because these functions use `ReleaseHold` internally.

Comment: `NMinimize[Hold[Print["hi"]; x^2], x]` causes my kernel to crash.   `NMinimize[Hold[x]^2, x]` complains and `NMinimize[Hold@Hold[x^2], x]` works; however, `NMinimize[Hold@Hold@Hold[x^2], x]` does not.  I suppose it could be `ReleaseHold`, but not in the ordinary way.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That pretty much settles that this is not supported functionality.  I think it is good to have this information in a Q/A.  You could consider answering.

Comment: I would absolutely agree with your guess that it is the internal handling of evaluation control which make these work accidentially. The question remains whether that indicates that these internally do more `ReleaseHold`s than necessary and whether that is intended or a lack of attention. In any case it seem to not cause much problems, I think?

Comment: I noticed this a while ago and suspected it to be due to the behavior of the `Experimental\`NumericalFunction`, which is definitely used by `NMinimize` and probably by the others. But I don't really know anything about this undocumented function and so can't elaborate further.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I took a rather shotgun approach to the question and got a range of behaviors.  The range is rather confusing, so I agree with Szabolcs's conclusion that using `Hold` this way is not supported.

First, `NMinimize[Hold[Print["hi"]; x^2], x]` prints `"hi"` and then **crashes the kernel,** while `NMinimize[Print["hi"]; x^2, x]` prints `"hi"` and returns `{0., {x -> 0.}}`.

Next consider the sequence

```
NMinimize[x^2, x]                  (* -> {0., {x -> 0.}} *)
NMinimize[Hold[x^2], x]            (* -> {5.55112*10^-17, {x -> -7.45058*10^-9}} *)
NMinimize[Hold@Hold[x^2], x]       (* -> {5.55112*10^-17, {x -> -7.45058*10^-9}} *)
NMinimize[Hold@Hold@Hold[x^2], x]  (* -> NMinimize::nnum error *)
```

as well as

```
NMinimize[Hold[x]^2, x]            (* -> NMinimize::nnum error *)
```

One or two `Holds` prevent symbolic analysis but allow the numeric function to be evaluated.  You have to really, really `Hold` the argument to stop evaluation.  A `Hold` inside the function is not released, so it is not a simple application of `ReleaseHold` to the argument that allows minimization of `Hold[x^2]`.

With `Plot`, you have to wrap the function *five times* with `Hold` to stop the function from being plotted.  `FindRoot` behaves similar to `NMinimize`, except that it does not crash the kernel.