# How do I use a FunctionCompile(d) function in FindMInimum

Tags: mathematical-optimization, function-compile, data-types

Suppose I would like to speed up the function in FindMinimum[function[variables],startingPoint] by compiling function

I've constructed a minimal working example to describe what I would like to do.

Here is the code without compile (Minimizing some spring energy between several points)

p is a list of points.

```
springEnergy[p_] := 
 Total@Total[(DistanceMatrix[p, 
       DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance] - 1)^2]

positions = CirclePoints[4];

variables = p[#] & /@ Range[Length[positions]]

startingPoint = MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {variables, positions}]
```

This works:

```
FindMinimum[
 springEnergy[variables], startingPoint
 
 ]
```

I'd like to do the same thing, but with a compiled springEnergy.
I believe this is functionally the same as springEnergy:

```
fc = FunctionCompile[
  Function[Typed[pos, TypeSpecifier["NumericArray"]["Real64", 2]],
   Module[{
     adm = 
      Typed[
         KernelFunction[
          DistanceMatrix], {TypeSpecifier["NumericArray"]["Real64", 
            2]} -> TypeSpecifier["NumericArray"]["Real64", 2]][pos] -
       Typed[KernelFunction[ConstantArray],
         {"Integer32", {"Integer32", "Integer32"}} -> 
          TypeSpecifier["NumericArray"]["Real64", 2]][
        1, {Length[pos], Length[pos]}]
     },
    Total[Total[adm^2]]
    ]
   ]
  ]

fc[NumericArray[N@positions]] == springEnergy[N@positions]
(*True*)
```

However,

```
FindMinimum[
 fc[NumericArray[variables]], startingPoint
 ]
```

complains because--I think--FindMinimum calls the initial point symbolically.  Normally, I get around that by specifying _?NumericQ on the calling function.  I tried to so something like that with a wrapper function:

```
wrapper[variables_NumericArray] := fc[variables]
```

But, that doesn't prevent the initial symbolic call by FindMinimum:

```
FindMinimum[
 wrapper[variables], startingPoint
 ]
```

Comment: Perhaps `wrapper[variables_?MatrixQ] := fc[variables]; FindMinimum[wrapper[variables], startingPoint]`

Comment: `FindMinimum[Inactivate@fc[variables], startingPoint]` also works

Comment: @SimonWoods.  Excellent.  Both solutions work. Bravo.  Inactivate would never occurred to me.  I don't quite understand *why* it works.
Also, the two solutions you give are about the same speed. But, good news, even for this simple problem, your solution gives a factor of two speed up.
If you post this as an answer--I'll accept with thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the right idea, but `_NumericArray` will only match explicit `NumericArray` expressions, not arrays of numbers in general. So your wrapper function isn't doing what you intend. Since you're working in 2D a suitable pattern for the wrapper is `_?MatrixQ` which will match the 2D numeric array but not the 1D symbolic array.

```
wrapper[variables_?MatrixQ] := fc[variables]

FindMinimum[wrapper[variables], startingPoint]
(* {4.34315, {p[1] -> {0.426777, -0.426777}, p[2] -> {0.426777, 0.426777}, 
  p[3] -> {-0.426777, 0.426777}, p[4] -> {-0.426777, -0.426777}}} *)
```

An alternative is to use `Inactivate`, which prevents the initial evaluation of `fc` with symbolic arguments, but gets removed (by an internal `Activate`) for the numeric calculations.

```
FindMinimum[Inactivate@fc[variables], startingPoint]
(* {4.34315, {p[1] -> {0.426777, -0.426777}, p[2] -> {0.426777, 0.426777}, 
  p[3] -> {-0.426777, 0.426777}, p[4] -> {-0.426777, -0.426777}}} *)
```

Comment: Great advice and appreciated. Accepted as answered.

Comment: How did you find that `Inactivate` works in this case and is internally activated? It is such a helpful feature that I think it should be more visible. Is that somehow documented or did you just find it by trial and error. Would be nice to have a list of function for which that works and confirmation from WRI that this is supported...

Comment: @AlbertRetey I recalled seeing `Hold` used in a similar way in the past (eg https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43318/862) and just tried `Inactivate` on a hunch. You can see that it is internally activated by the errors if you wrap the whole thing in `Block[{Activate}, ... ]`. I assume the lack of documentation means this is accidental, or at least untested, behaviour. I've only tried it on this example so no idea if it works more widely.

Comment: OK, thanks. That makes sense, although I would wish these things would be documented (=specified) a bit clearer by WRI...