# Memory problems when fitting large (correlated) datasets

Tags: fitting, memory

I am trying to fit some complicated function that depends on 18 parameters.
The problematic is that I have a large correlated dataset (336 points).

When fitting, for simplicity, taking only the diagonal errors with `NonlinearModelFit`, the fit is extremely quick (0.15s). If, instead, I construct the chi-square function myself and use `FindMinimum`, it takes 8s and get the same result. If using `NMinimize` with good boundaries for the parameters, I get the same result in 28s.

Now, the problem is when I try to fit with the full covariance matrix. Now, I construct the chi squared function myself and try to use `FindMinimum` or `NMinimize`. The problem is that I get the following message:

> No more memory available.
> Mathematica kernel has shut down.
> Try quitting other applications and then retry

and the fit of course stops and the kernel is empty.

Actually, if I try just to create the chi-square function itself, the same problem happens. I guess the problem is a sum of 336^2 terms with a complicated function resulting in a too long expression.

My naive workaround was to modify the function to be fitted `f[x_,a_,b_,...]` as `f[x_?NumericQ,a_?NumericQ,b_?NumericQ,...]` to prevent symbolic evaluation and to get ran out of memory.
This wasn't actually enough, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37182/why-is-nminimize-trying-to-evaluate-my-function-analytically-instead-of-numeri). Further, even for simple fits, setting the inputs as `?NumericQ` will slow down the minimization considerably. I used then in `FindMinimum` the `Hold[]` attribute as in the previous [thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37182/why-is-nminimize-trying-to-evaluate-my-function-analytically-instead-of-numeri), but then the fit is far from ideal (even if considering diagonal errors only) and gives the message

> Encountered a gradient that is effectively zero. The result returned may not be a minimum; it may be a maximum or a saddle point.

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: Your question is hard to answer in general. Perhaps if you showed your code so far and a sample of your dataset then some specific suggestions could be made.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will try to provide a MWE (the function is just too lengthy and with a simpler one no problem arises). 

By the way, I could try on a (better) different computer and it works without problem. However, I would prefer to use my own computer.

Comment: Giving the fixed and random effects (covariance structure) in LaTeX form rather than just *Mathematica* code would also be helpful so that the definition of "correlated data" could be understood.

Comment: Essentially, the experimentalists provide a set of data points (336) together with the covariance matrix (336*336 entries).
I suspect the form its not essential, as the problem comes when creating such a long chi square. I obtain the same error if using a covariance matrix with the same size with random numbers as input. 
I believe the key points are (i) the length of the covariance matrix (ii) the complicated function. The latter is given in analytic form including logs, square roots, powers,... but is rather lengthy. I checked that, for a simple function, the problem would not exist.

Comment: From your description of the covariance matrix it appears that you are not estimating any covariance terms but rather those are given as known.  (That seems more than a bit unbelievable that covariance terms would be known but the terms almost always easier to estimate are not.  But let's ignore that for now.)  Why you think in terms of a minimizing a chisquare is also a bit odd.  Why not directly find the maximum likelihood estimates by maximizing the likelihood?  *Mathematica*'s `LogLikelihood` function would seem to be what you want to use.

Comment: Probably it was jargon, I answered below to that. I used what you name the LogLikelihood. My apologies ofr the confusion. The covariance matrix for the different points are given by the experimentalists measuring those points and is splitted in to statistic and systematic uncertainties.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what particular chisquare statistic you're trying to minimize (or even why you'd want a chisquare statistic to minimize - certainly not the Sum(O-E)^2/E type) but obtaining the maximum likelihood estimates of the parameters should be relatively straightforward.

I'm also assuming that you think you know the true covariance matrix as opposed to estimating it along with the other parameters.

```
(* Sample size *)
n = 336;

(* Construct covariance matrix and associated functions *)
(* This is an autoregressive covariance matrix *)
σ = 4;
ρ = 0.5;
Σ = Table[σ^2 ρ^Abs[i - j], {i, n}, {j, n}];

(* Generate a simple prediction equation and simulated data *)
(* Normally distributed error from covariance matrix *)
SeedRandom[12345];
ϵ = RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[Σ], 1][[1]];
(* Function to fit *)
f[x_, a_, b_, c_] := a + b x + c Log[x]
x = Range[n];
y = f[x, 1, 1/2, 2] + ϵ;

(* Plot data *)
ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}]]
```

[image: Scatter plot of data]

Now define the log of the likelihood.  I've removed the parts that remain constant but have also included the full likelihood in comments in case one needs to compare results with other software.

```
(* logAbsDet=Log[Abs[Det[Σ]]] *)
ΣInverse = Inverse[Σ];
(* logL[y_,x_,a_,b_,c_]:=-(n Log[2π]+logAbsDet+(y-f[x,a,b,c]).ΣInverse.(y-f[x,a,b,c]))/2 *)
logL[y_, x_, a_, b_, c_] := -(y - f[x, a, b, c]) . ΣInverse . (y - f[x, a, b, c])/2 // N

(* Get starting values for parameters *)
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[Transpose[{x, y}], f[z, a0, b0, c0], {a0, b0, c0}, z]["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a0 -> 1.25527, b0 -> 0.507967, c0 -> 1.45971} *)

(* Maximum likelihood estimates *)
mle = FindMaximum[logL[y, x, a, b, c], {{a, a0}, {b, b0}, {c, c0}} /. nlm]
(* {-166.9, {a -> 0.252364, b -> 0.505238, c -> 1.75736}} *)

(* Estimated parameter covariance matrix *)
(cov = -Inverse[(D[logL[y, x, a, b, c], {{a, b, c}, 2}]) /. mle[[2]]]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Estimated parameter covariance matrix]

```
(* Estimated parameter correlation matrix *)
(cor = Table[cov[[i, j]]/Sqrt[cov[[i, i]] cov[[j, j]]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Estimated parameter correlation matrix]

We see that the parameter estimators are highly correlated.

Comment: Hi, and sorry for my delay. Indeed, that's the way I proceeded (perhaps I was not quite explicit).
Essentially, I created your `logL` function for my data (appart from the minus sign and the factor of 2, that's what I call the chi square). 
The problem is that, when I create the `logL` function, my computer runs out of memory and the kernel is restarted. I guess the problem is the length of my function (containing logs, square roots, etc.. and 18 parameters), as doing an example like yours works easily and better computers (I have 4GB ram on my laptop) proceeds easily.

Comment: If the objective is to get your function and estimation working on your 4GB laptop, then I would suggest determining where things stop working.  Taking the inverse of the covariance matrix?  If so, then it seems hopeless.  If it's at the `NonlinearModelFit` stage, then it might also be hopeless.  But if it's at the last stage (`FindMaximum`), then maybe some of your equation is linear in some of the parameters which means you can reduce the number of parameters in the `FindMaximum`.  But without knowing the function you're trying to fit, that's only a guess.

Comment: Actually, the problem is at computing the `logL`. The inverse covariance matrix is computed without problems indeed. Apparently, Mathematica precomputes the expression for `logL` (note we have 336^2 long expressions). 
That's why I tried to append `?NumericQ` to prevent evaluation before the model is given a point and produces a number. However, it turns out that fitting this way is terribly time consuming and couldn't produce results with `FindMinimum` (I don't have your overall - sign, so it is equivalent) or `NMinimize`. That was funny...
Thanks a lot for your help anyway!

Comment: With 18 parameters (and based on your recent question), I would bet that your model is linear in the parameters.  That means generalized least squares is what you want (as I mentioned in an answer to your most recent question).  That is not an iterative approach which means there is an explicit formula for the estimates and the covariance matrix for the estimates.